# Meaning of "gehören" with "an"

Tags: meaning

I see the following advertisement tag line:

> Auf und Abs gehören an die Börse. Nicht in den Kopf.

and I have two questions.

1. *gehören* meaning. Does it mean here *as part of* with the preposition *zu*? I know the other meaning of *gehören* is *belong to* without *zu*. What is the meaning here *gehören an + AKK*? Is the following sentence grammatically valid

> Auf und Abs gehören zum Leben (As I translate from English *Up and downs are part of life*)?

2. Why there is an *s* after *Ab* as *Abs*? Does that imply plural?

Comment: Thanks Olafant for your reformatting of the question. I will note that in my future questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In

   > Auf und Abs gehören an die Börse. Nicht in den Kopf.

   the *an* belongs to *an die Börse*, not to *gehören*. You can see it in the second part of the statement:

   > [Auf und Abs gehören] nicht *in den Kopf*.

   So I think translating *gehören + Akk.* here with *to belong to/in/at* fits quite well.

   > Das Geschirr gehört in die Küche.
   > Oscar gehört in die Tonne.
   > Die Brille gehört auf die Nase.

   *Is part of* is a good translation of *gehören zu (Dat.)* imo.

   > Klappern gehört zum Handwerk.
   > Auf und Abs gehören zum Leben.
2. You're right. The *s* in *Auf und Abs* marks plural.

Comment: Thanks Olafant for your confirmation. And especially the reference to "nicht in den Kopf.", which I overlooked.

Comment: You're welcome. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to elaborate @Olafants answer a bit.

#### Question 1: *gehören* + direction (not necessarily accusative)

The construction in question is not necessarily *gehören + accusative*, but ***gehören + direction***. In your sentence, the accusative is governed by the preposition *an*, not by *gehören*.  The direction could as well be given by an adverb instead:

> Auf und Abs gehören dorthin, nicht hierher.

*Gehören + direction* is an **idiomatic phrase with several meanings and no complete equivalent in English**. This insight is crucial here because in your example, two slightly different meanings are made use of:

1. *Auf und Abs **gehören** an die Börse* states that *ups and downs **should** happen on (and be limited to) the stock exchange*. The [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geh%C3%B6ren#d-1-3) gives this meaning as subitem of § 3 only by an example:

> *⟨jmd. gehört ins Bett⟩ jmd. müsste eigentlich ins Bett*.

2. *[Auf und Abs **gehören**] **nicht** in den Kopf*, however, matches the *negation* of the parent item in the DWDS, 'to be in the right place, to fit'. Thus it translates to 'to be out of place, to misfit'. The negation is actually so common that the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehoeren) manages to give *only* negated examples for this meaning (§ 3) besides the variant mentioned above:

> - das Fahrrad gehört nicht in die Wohnung
> - das gehört nicht hierher

On the whole, I would translate your example sentence as:

> Ups and downs are supposed to happen on the stock exchange, not in the head.

#### Question 2: *Die Auf und Abs* (shouldn't it be *Auf-und-Abs*?)

First of all: yes, it's plural, and seeing that it is a fixed phrase, the plural *-s* must also modify *Auf*, otherwise it would read **das Auf und die Abs*. This aspect seems quite strange to me.

I found very little resources on the orthographical and grammatical properties of pluralized phrases that consist out of multiple nominalized adverbs. The [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Substantivierte-Adverbien-Prapositionen-u) even introduces its online article on that topic with *Doch müssen bei solch einem Hin und Her nicht Bindestriche her?* without ever picking up that question again. Apparently, the *Duden-Grammatik* doesn't concern itself with the plural of multi-part nominalized phrases either. While [*das Auf und Ab*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Auf_und_Ab) is not hyphenated for some reason, to me it seems necessary to do so if the composition is pluralized as a whole:

> die Auf-und-Abs

vs.

> ?die Auf**s** und Abs

The latter parallels *up**s** and downs* in English, but virtually never occurs in German.

Comment: "Auf und Abs" - considering this comes from an advertisement there is a certain "freedom" in handling German grammar. Plus as the phrase irritates it can be considered an attention seeker.

Comment: Thanks amadeusamadeus for your detailed answer, especially the comment on negation.